# Snap autoupdate broke firefox this morning

Tags: firefox, snap

Snap's autoupdate completely broke Firefox this morning on my machine, and I'm not sure how to fix it. When I run Firefox it gives me this error:

```
cannot locate base snap core20: No such file or directory
```

Ok so I check to see what the status of core20 is:

```
$ snap list
Name                       Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher        Notes
core20                     20221212                    1778   latest/stable    canonical✓       base,disabled
```

Why is core20 disabled? Oh it has the autorefresh change in progress.

```
$ sudo snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
10   Doing   today at 06:46 PST  -                   Auto-refresh snap "core20"
```

That's been going nowhere for hours. Let's abort and manually remove and re-add core20.

```
$ sudo snap abort 10
$ sudo snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
10   Abort   today at 06:46 PST  -                   Auto-refresh snap "core20"
$ sudo snap remove core20
error: snap "core20" has "auto-refresh" change in progress
```

So even though I've aborted the auto-refresh snap still thinks it's in progress. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Is the manually replaced core20 still the old version from 20221212, rev 1778?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snapd stores at least one older version of each snap. You can list all versions installed (current and previous ones not removed yet) by `snap list --all`.

To return to an older, working version, run `sudo snap revert name_of_the_snap`, in your case `sudo snap revert core20`. You may need to kill the update process before or reboot your machine to stop the hanging refresh process.